# Spring Boot Jpa, cannot map only foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can map only id(foreign key) with @ManyToOne? I don't want whole object to be mapped..

```
@Id
private UUID id;
private String name;
private double price;
private String image;
private String ingredients;
private String description;

@ManyToOne
private CategoryImpl category;

public FoodDto mapToDto() {
    return new FoodDtoImpl(this.getId(), this.getName(), this.getPrice(), this.getImage(),
            this.getIngredients(), this.getDescription(),this.getCategory());
}

public void generateId(){
    this.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to map it as a simple column instead of entity relationship:

```java
@Id
private UUID id;
private String name;
private double price;
private String image;
private String ingredients;
private String description;
@Column(name="CATEGORY_ID". // name is just an example
private UUID categoryId;
```

You may remove `@Column` if the name of the property matches the column name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what a stupid mistake by me, have a great day!